# Rewrite URL Custom Post Type Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Necesito saber como cambiar una URL en 2 Custom Post Type que tengo

Ahora mismo me devuelve la url de la siguiente manera:

> **wordp.test/ciudad/madrid** necesito que sea de esta manera **wordp.test/servicio-madrid**
>
> **wordp.test/poblacion/mostoles** necesito que sea de esta manera **wordp.test/servicio-mostoles**

Se que las urls se pueden cambiar desde mi plugin con código, pero no encuentro por donde empezar, he hecho pruebas pero no funciona siempre me acaba poniendo la dichosa "/" de separado cuando yo quiero que sea un "-".

Mis CTPs son asi:

**Ciudades**

```
add_action( 'init', 'ciudades', 0 );
function ciudades() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'ciudades', 'Post Type General Name', 'ciudades' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'ciudad', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'ciudades' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Ciudades', 'ciudades' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Post Type', 'ciudades' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'ciudades' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'ciudades' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'ciudades' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'Todos', 'ciudades' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'ciudades' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Nuevo', 'ciudades' ),

    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                  => 'ciudad',
        'with_front'            => false,
        'pages'                 => true,
        'feeds'                 => true,
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'ciudad', 'ciudades' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Ciudades, almacenamiento de ciudades', 'ciudades' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'page-atributes' ),
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-admin-site-alt3',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'query_var'             => 'ciudad',
        'rewrite'               => $rewrite,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'ciudades', $args );

}
```

**Poblaciones**

```
add_action( 'init', 'poblaciones', 0 );
function poblaciones() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'poblaciones', 'Post Type General Name', 'poblaciones' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'poblacion', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'poblaciones' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Poblaciones', 'poblaciones' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Post Type', 'poblaciones' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'poblaciones' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'poblaciones' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'poblaciones' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'Todos', 'poblaciones' ),

    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                  => 'poblacion',
        'with_front'            => false,
        'pages'                 => true,
        'feeds'                 => true,
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'poblacion', 'poblaciones' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Poblaciones, almacenamiento de poblaciones', 'poblaciones' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'page-attributes' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-admin-site-alt3',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'query_var'             => 'poblacion',
        'rewrite'               => $rewrite,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'poblaciones', $args );

}
```

Por su puesto, he cambiado el parametro slug de cada uno de ellos, por `servicio-`, pero igual me forma la URL `wordp.test/servicio-/madrid` y si lo hago en el CPT de poblaciones me arroja un 404, por que chocan los 2 slugs.

He encontrado un código que funciona pero a medias, todavía falta incorporar `servicio-` antes de `madrid`.

Pongo el código, este elimina `/ciudad`.

```
function gp_remove_cpt_slug($post_link, $post)
{
    if ('ciudades' === $post->post_type && 'publish' === $post->post_status) {
        $post_link = str_replace('/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link);

    }
    return $post_link;
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'gp_remove_cpt_slug', 10, 2);

function gp_add_cpt_post_names_to_main_query($query)
{
    // Bail if this is not the main query.
    if (!$query->is_main_query()) {
        return;
    }
    // Bail if this query doesn't match our very specific rewrite rule.
    if (!isset($query->query['page']) || 2 !== count($query->query)) {
        return;
    }
    // Bail if we're not querying based on the post name.
    if (empty($query->query['name'])) {
        return;
    }
    // Add CPT to the list of post types WP will include when it queries based on the post name.
    $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'page', 'ciudades'));
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'gp_add_cpt_post_names_to_main_query');
```

Este `filter` y `action` me devuelve `wordp.test/ciudad`.

Si vario la linea:

```
$post_link = str_replace('/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/servicio-', $post_link);
```

Ahí si sale el enlace `wordp.test/servicio-madrid`, claro que no funciona devuelve 404 y devuelve este error.

> wpdb::prepare ha sido llamada de forma incorrecta. La consulta solo
>   esperaba un marcador de posición, pero se ha enviado un array de
>   varios marcadores de posición.

Gracias

Comment: No es posible de manera automática con la estructura de URL de WordPress asignar un mismo slug a dos tipos de post distintos. Hay alguna razón para elegir un tipo distinto si ambos son servicio-...?